# ASP.net Visual studio 2008 SQL Data Source

Tags: asp.net, date, datetime, gridview, dbtype

I am working on a GridView control where I wanted to display several data in the grid. The columns are; 2 string names, 1 integer, and datetime. When I want to input data to show in the grid to make sure it works, an exception error (a code given from a professor) shows up saying;

> System.ArgumentException: The version of SQL Server in use does not
>   support datatype 'date'.

However, I figure what was the problem. In my HTML source, I was looking in the Delete, Update, Insert Parameters, in the Date column, I had; Dbtype="date". I have to change it to; Type="DateTime" and it works.

What caused it to be Dbtype="date" instead of Type="DateTime"?
Much appreciated when answered.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably your mssql server veriosn is 2005 , so it doesn't support "date" as datatype

Answer (score 0):

Actually, **DATE** is a datatype introduced in MS SQL Server 2008, then in MS SQL Server 2012. Most probably you're using MS SQL Server 2005 or earlier. Please check the version of your SQL Server.

I hope it helps you.

Comment: Is there a way I can locate which version of MS SQL server that I am using?

Comment: Yes, of course. There are many ways to do that. If you're using an SQL Server Management Studio, simply type "select @@version as version" in the query window then press the F5 key to run the command.